# Is it okay to hide a search bar if there are less than 3 searchable items?

Tags: web-app, search

#### The Context

In part of our app, users must select different sessions to register for within their organization. Sometimes that organization has 20 sessions, sometimes it has only 1 or 2.

**What are possible drawbacks to hiding the search bar in the latter case?**

#### Our Position

So far, we've decided that no, there is nothing wrong with doing this. Some users become confused by the fact that there *is* a search bar when there's only one session, thinking they must be missing something.

We see little or no downside to hiding the search bar in these instances unless **we** are the ones missing something?

---

#### Thank you!

Thank you both for you all for your insight, it's been very helpful.

Comment: There may be a marketing/business angle here that would be killing two birds with one stone- is there any value to *allowing* a search for all sessions, but then showing the ones they can't attend as disabled ("Your organization is not signed up for these - click here to request this session!") or would it be completely off-topic...

Comment: We work B2B, our clients work B2C. We help our clients enroll their customers in the sessions _they_ offer, so this won't make sense for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be careful with making these kinds of decisions for your users. Based on the current description, **this kind of "enhancement" has absolutely no visibility to the user**.

I think it'd be more frustrating for a user who has seen a feature before, but **for some entirely invisible reason** can't seem to find it now. The user has no idea that that feature's availability is tied to the number of sessions, so to base its availability on that number would be unpredictable.

Yes, it may confuse some to have a search with only one item, but I think you're better off addressing that confusion. For example:

[image: Search bar with Search all 1 items placeholder text]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0cXFa.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Additionally, providing this feature all the time allows a user to see that, yes, your application can be used to manage large numbers of sessions in the event that their usage increases.

Comment: nice touch on enumerating the number of items in the search placeholder.

Comment: We discussed this solution as well - thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

If you do decide to hide the search box (I'm very hesitant on that!), **at least label the number of sessions available at all times**. Otherwise users may question if the results are incomplete, and then you start introducing doubt about reliability.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT47oM.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>